# Disk space - empty Appdata/Local folder

Tags: windows-7

I recently found that my hard drive is almost full. My Appdata/Local/Microsoft/Outlook is like 30 GB and my Appdata/Local/Microsoft/Google Sync is like 10 GB. Can I empty the folders? When I empty both folder, will I get problem? Appdata/Local files could be removed or?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer this question with the amount of information given without telling you something you already know.

Yes, you will have problems with Outlook and Google Sync if you delete Appdata files. I can't say to what extent, but there's obviously a reason they're there. A better solution is to use Outlook to delete old emails, and use Google Sync to delete files you no longer need to sync.